# VB 2010: How to calculate a date difference?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like do make a program which returns you how old you are, in years, months, weeks and days. But I didn't get it to compare different times.

Input is a string which looks like 01.01.2011 (dd.mm.yyyy).

Please, can somebody help?

Thanks very much!

EDIT:

My code so far is this:

```
Try
        dim date1 as string = '01.01.2011'
        ' Today
        Dim date2 As Date
        date2 = Date.Now
        ' number of seconds since date1
        Dim seconds As Long
        seconds = DateDiff("s", date1, date2)
        lbl_seconds.Text = seconds.ToString & " Seconds"
        ' Number of minutes since date1
        Dim Minutes As Long
        Minutes = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
        lbl_minutes.Text = Minutes.ToString & " Minutes"
        ' Number of hours since date1
        Dim hours As Long
        hours = DateDiff("h", date1, date2)
        lbl_hours.Text = hours.ToString & " Hours"
        ' Days
        Dim days As Long
        days = DateDiff("d", date1, date2)
        lbl_days.Text = days.ToString & " Days"
        ' weeks
        Dim weeks As Long
        weeks = DateDiff("ww", date1, date2)
        lbl_weeks.Text = weeks.ToString & " Weeks"
        'months
        Dim months As Long
        months = DateDiff("m", date1, date2)
        lbl_months.Text = months.ToString & " Months"
        ' Years
        Dim years As Long
        years = DateDiff("yyyy", date1, date2)
        lbl_years.Text = years.ToString & " Years"


    Catch ex As Exception
        date1 = "01.01.2011"
        MsgBox("not a valid date given!")
    End Try
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: what I found is that DateDiff returns with years always a value for the whole year (so all with birth in 2000 are now 11 years old), so I'd have to calculate it with seconds or days - but how to calculate with leapyears?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DateDiff is a VB function and is not part of the standard .Net library (So C# can't use it).

It's easier to use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class and the [toString() method with Custom TimeSpan Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) to get what you want.

**Edit:**

Here's the code, you can compare result to http://www.easycalculation.com/date-day/age-calculator.php:

```
Dim birthday As New DateTime(1990, 1, 1)
Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthday)

Dim years As Integer, months As Integer, days As Integer, hours As Integer, minutes As Integer, seconds As Integer

' compute difference in total months
months = 12 * (DateTime.Now.Year - birthday.Year) + (DateTime.Now.Month - birthday.Month)

' based upon the 'days',
' adjust months & compute actual days difference
If DateTime.Now.Day < birthday.Day Then
    months -= 1
    days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(birthday.Year, birthday.Month) - birthday.Day + DateTime.Now.Day
Else
    days = DateTime.Now.Day - birthday.Day
End If
' compute years & actual months
years = Math.Floor(months / 12)
months -= years * 12

hours = ts.Hours
minutes = ts.Minutes
seconds = ts.Seconds
```

Comment: the standard is not important at all, i just want to calculate it properly.

Comment: I would probably store `DateTime.Now` in a local variable so that the calculations remain consistent.  Though unlikely, it is possible that a second passes after midnight on December 31 while the code is running which would return an interesting value, I think.  So at line 3 you would have `DateTime.Now` = 12/31/2011 11:59 p.m.  In line 7, you could have `DateTime.Now` = 01/01/2012 12:00 a.m.  This is just something to consider.

Comment: DateDiff is part of the VisualBasic namespace, which IS available to C# with a simple reference addition.  And this is exactly the type of situation where you'd want to use it.

Comment: I'm confused - you establish the TimeSpan on line 2.  You then use it on line 21.  What is all the stuff in between?  If you want the number of days across the given TimeSpan, couldn't you just do ts.Days?  According to the pop-up description, "Gets the number of whole days represented by the current TimeSpan structure" - is that not giving us the number of total days in the TimeSpan?  Which you can then divide by 365, 12, whatever, adjust for leap years, etc.